# View an XML file without any carriage returns or other text formatting as a tree

Tags: emacs, xml, format

I've opened an XML file in emacs, and it's the output from a web request so it's just in one long line. Can I execute a command to format it into a tree structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the region you want to format and call M-x sgml-pretty-print